# How to handle advanced search with dynamic filtering addition using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, advanced-search

Below is the form for advanced search:

[image: Advanced Search Box]

I am able to create a URL and parameters for document sections but I am unable to think of a process to handle the "Add Property Restrictions" section as the property can be added up to 5 times and it depends on the end user.

Like Below:

[image: Advanced with Dynamic User Entries]

So I want to handle it in AngularJS with addition/deletion and dynamic changes on the go and also to form the URL (GET/POST) to send the data for searching to the API for the back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this using an array of objects inside your model.

The structure of your model will be something like

```
let dataModel = {
      'allwords': '',
      'exact_phrase':'',
      /// .. the rest of your basic search model variables

      'property_res': [ {'property':'','action':'contains','value':'','logical_operator':'and'} ]
}
```

In your template, you will dynamicaly generate the list of property restrictions with ng-repeat  of `dataModel['property_res']`

As for the "add property" - you just implement click handler that will append annother object (with same structure as initial row) to your `dataModel['property_res']` , ng-repeat will take care of the rest.

To get the values to your POST request, you simly iterate through the array of `dataModel['property_res']` and construct your variables, or you can just JSON.serialize() it and handle it on your server side.

Hope this will get you going!

**EDIT**

Adding example of ng-repeat rendering:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
    
   $scope.dataModel = {
      'property_res': [ {'property':'','action':'contains','value':'','logical_operator':'and'} ]
   }
   
   $scope.addRow = function(){
      $scope.dataModel['property_res'].push({'property':'','action':'contains','value':'','logical_operator':'and'})
   }
   $scope.showModel= function(){
      console.log($scope.dataModel)
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    
     <h1>Property restrictions:</h1>
     <div ng-repeat="ps in dataModel.property_res">
       <select ng-model="ps.property">
         <option value="">Pick property</option>
         <option value="Property 1">Property 1</option>
         <option value="Property 2">Property 2</option>
       </select>
       <select ng-model="ps.action">
         <option value="doesn't contain">doesn't contain</option>
         <option value="contains">contains</option>
         
       </select>
       <input ng-model="ps.value">
       <select ng-model="ps.logical_operator">
         <option value="or">or</option>
         <option value="and">and</option>
         
       </select>
     </div>
     <hr>
     <div><button ng-click="addRow()">Add Row</button></div>
     <hr>
     <div><button ng-click="showModel()">Console Log Model</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would be happy and gratefull if you can show me how to do that on the view with ng-repeat as i am not getting sure of the code hoiw to do it with dynamic addition and maintenance of the property addition in advanced search. I could throughly get in terms of how the json to be made for POST data.

Comment: I've added angular 1 example snippet to demonstrate what i mean

Comment: Perfect @mike_t ... Thanks for the explanatory code which has cleared my view and even learnt a new thing.. Cheers mate :)